# Android SlidingTabLayout - 1st Tab Always selected unless clicked

Tags: android, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I've successfully implemented Google's SlidingTabLayout with custom icons. every icon has 2 versions, selected/unselected.

When my application starts, the first tab (out of 4) shows a selected state which is fine.

Thereafter, if I click on any of the remaining 3 tabs, 2/3/4 the new tab gets highlighted, however the first tab still continues to be in a selected state. However, once I click on the first tab and then navigate between any of the remaining tabs, my issue is resolved.
So, is there any way I can trigger the first tab to be clicked automatically when the activity is created?

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;
    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;
    private int mTitleOffset;
    private Context context;
    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;
    private Intent intent;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;
    private boolean loaded = false;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        this.intent = intent;
        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    //    /** //     * Set the custom {@link com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget.SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer} to be used. //     * //     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use //     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve //     * similar effects. //     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    //    /** //     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget.SlidingTabLayout} you are //
* required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so //     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly. //     * //     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) //  
*/
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId  id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */


    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("userProfileData", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String profileInfo = prefs.getString("profiledata", null);
            populateTabStripParent();



        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {

        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    public void populateTabStripParent() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        View tabView = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, mTabStrip,
                    false);

            ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_icon);
            iconImageView.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt((String) adapter.getPageTitle(i))));

            if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == i) {
                iconImageView.setSelected(true);
            }
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView, layoutParams);
        }
    }





    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    //    /** //     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with //     * {@link
#setCustomTabColorizer(com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget.SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer)}. //     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //Clear old selection and make new
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(false);


            }
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);

            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post some code pls, your selector...

Comment: you can take a look. I've pasted my modified SlidingTabLayout.